# Firestore, .onSnapshot unsubscribe blocks page rendering

Tags: javascript, firebase, vue.js, google-cloud-firestore

I'm using Firebase and Firestore in javascript to show a collection in real time (around 400 elements) using .onSnapshot:

```
collectionRef = db.collection('elements').doc(id).collection('subelements')
const unsubscribe = collectionRef.onSnapshot((q)=>{
     // update a elements variable
});
```

I'm having no problem retrieving the list and updating it when it changes, however, when I execute "unsubscribe()" to stop receiving updates all my page freeze for around 600ms.

[image]

The call of unsubscribe itself is not blocking execution (I guess is asynchronous) but the rendering freezes at some point after I call unsubscribe. This doesn't happen with smaller collections or if I don't unsubscribe for them.

I'm using Vue and unsubscribing on "beforeDestroy"

*UPDATE*
Similar performance problems, where the page interaction freezes happen when performing a get() operation on the same list. After removing all processing on the callback and returning an empty array:

[image]

Comment: Without saying exactly what you're doing inside the onSnapshot handler, it's impossible to diagnose what could be taking so much time.  You're probably doing a lot of work for those 400 documents.

Comment: The performance problem described here is on unsubscribe, not on the snapshot callback. The same problem appears when retrieving the elements (either with get and onSnapshot) even removing all processing on the callback (returning empty array).

Comment: Without seeing your entire project, it's impossible to track down specific performance issues.  If you are certain about what's the problem, and it's in a Firebase SDK, you should [file a bug report](https://firebase.google.com/support/contact/bugs-features/) with Firebase support and send an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (and I do mean **minimal**) that can reproduce the problem.

Comment: I'll keep digging into it to compare with a minimal code, but I cannot think on what may cause when I'm returning an empty list. Thank @DougStevenson